# Problem with text position in math underbrace

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to write under a system of equation that it is impossible with the following code:

```
\[\underbrace{\begin{cases}
a = -1\\
b=2\\
(-1-4)-i(2+8)=-8i\implies -5 -10i = -8i
\end{cases}_{\text{Sistema impossibile}}}\bigcup\begin{cases}
a=0\\
b=2\\
-i(2^3)=-8i
\end{cases}\]
```

The problem is that the text gets positioned badly as you can see in the pic:[image]

How can I get the text to actually be under the brace and not there? Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: What would `\bigcup` mean? Do you perhaps mean `\lor`?

Comment: \bigcup gets the big union symbol(there is a second system which I haven't showed in the picture). What's \lor for?

Comment: You can contact the user egreg using directly the `@ + name`, because probably he not see your comment.

Comment: @user66094 `\bigcup` is meaningless in that context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An \underbrace positions its label the way the \sum operator gets its lower limit: entered as a subscript. In the code sample the subscript label comes right after `\end{cases}` instead of after the whole `\underbrace{...}` due to a misplaced close-brace character (so the intended label was an ordinary subscript for the `cases` environment).  Moving the brace to come before the subscript fixes the trouble, as in this MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[\underbrace{\begin{cases}
a = -1\\
b=2\\
(-1-4)-i(2+8)=-8i\implies -5 -10i = -8i
\end{cases}}_{\text{Sistema impossibile}}\bigcup
\begin{cases}
a=0\\
b=2\\
-i(2^3)=-8i
\end{cases}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: underbrace with under-label positioned properly]

---

Addendum with the `\lor` command as by comment of the user **@egreg**.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[\underbrace{\begin{cases}
a = -1\\
b=2\\
(-1-4)-i(2+8)=-8i\implies -5 -10i = -8i
\end{cases}}_{\text{Sistema impossibile}}\lor
\begin{cases}
a=0\\
b=2\\
-i(2^3)=-8i
\end{cases}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Using logical-or between the cases]

Comment: Thank you, it worked

Comment: Just to point out what the problem & solution were: The question had a misplaced close-brace after `\end{cases}`, so \underbrace took both the cases environment plus the subscript as its first argument.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau Hi, can I help this favour, please? I'm not very good, often, to explain in English language the problem. If I use the translator I not know if the english motivation is correct or not correct. On your comment I am agree totally with you. At this moment I'm writing, for example, without the use of translator. (Before I think in Italian and after my mind translate in english :-( ). Can you edit adding your comment, please?

Comment: Oh, OK @Sebastiano. I also agree completely with your answer, but will add a few words -- in English :-)

Comment: @DonaldArseneau :-) welcome for your edit.....and thank you. At this moment my mind it is to school for my students: I'm using Google Suite, electronic papers for the exercises and now I'm in tilt. :-( GRazieeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.